How start Google map with trip active in Picture in Picture mode on button click in Flutter or in android
I am using map_launcher to launch a google map.
When I open Google Maps, I need to click the "Start" button to begin navigation on the map. Is there a way to display the Google Map as shown in the image without needing to do this?
like this
Currently I am opening map with showDirections() function provided by map_launcher
map?.showDirections(
      destination: Coords(
           widget.place.latLng2.latitude,
           widget.place.latLng2.longitude,
      ),
      destinationTitle: widget.place.address.split(",")[0],
);

